# Delphi 10.4.2 "could not find wizard gexperts" error on starting

Tags: delphi, gexperts

I have just installed Delphi 10.4.2. It runs fine, but every time it strarts I get this error message: "Could not find Wizard C:...\Gexperts for Rad Studio 10.4\GExpertsRS104.dll"
Is there a way to install GExperts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download from http://www.gexperts.org/download/ and install it.
Or this one: https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/

Comment: gexperts.org only links to gexperts.dummzeuch.de for the latest versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed it, workd fine.

Answer (score 3):

A version for Delphi 10.4.1 is available from https://gexperts.dummzeuch.de. As far as I know it also works with Delphi 10.4.2. Alternatively get the source code and compile it yourself (link on that page).

But why does the Delphi IDE try to load GExperts? Normally it only does that if you have installed it. Did you may be migrate settings from an older Delphi version where you had it installed?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed it, workd fine.